# How to Evaluate $\int{\rm}\left({x^3}+x^\frac{1}{3}\right)\sqrt{x} \, dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

I admit to having challenges in this, and i want some help. I have not tried anything so hints aor answers will be allowed as i work towards knowing how to do them.

Given this: $$\int{\rm}\left({x^3}+x^\frac{1}{3}\right)\sqrt{x} \, dx $$

Comment: **HINT**: $\sqrt{x}$ can be written as $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$. You can then "foil" that into the braces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have wanted to know where you have difficulties but this is how i would have approached the situation.

$$\int{\rm}\left({x^3}+x^\frac{1}{3}\right)\sqrt{x} dx $$

= $$\int{\rm}\left(x^{{3}+{\frac {1}{2}}}+x^{\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2}}\right) dx $$

=$$  \int{\rm}\left(x^{\frac {7}{2}}+x^{\frac{5}{6}}\right)dx $$

=$$ \frac{2}{9}x^\frac{9}{2} + \frac{6}{11}x^\frac{11}{6} + C $$

Comment: I only wish i could understand this like you do.

Comment: Just practice and more practice.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$\sqrt{x}=x^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
and
$$x^a\times x^b=x^{a+b}$$
Can you use this to distribute out $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$?

Answer (score 3):

HINT : Note that $\sqrt x=x^{\frac 12}$, so
$$\left(x^3+x^{\frac 13}\right)\sqrt x=x^{3+\frac 12}+x^{\frac 13+\frac 12}$$
and
$$\int x^a dx=\frac{1}{a+1}x^{a+1}+C$$
for $a\not=-1$.